# How to deep_transform_values with keys in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, activesupport

Active Support's `deep_transform_values` recursively transforms all values of a hash. However, is there a similar method that would allow to access the keys of values while transforming?

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```rb
keys_not_to_transform = ['id', 'count']

response = { result: 'ok', errors: [], data: { id: '123', price: '100.0', quotes: ['1.0', '2.0'] }, count: 10 }
response.deep_transform_values! do |key, value|
  # Use value's key to help decide what to do
  return value if keys_not_to_transform.any? key.to_s

  s = value.to_s
  if s.present? && /\A[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?\z/.match?(s)
    return BigDecimal(s)
  else
    value
  end
end

#Expected result 
# =>{:result=>"ok", :errors=>[], :data=>{:id=>"123", :price=>0.1e3, :quotes=>[0.1e1, 0.2e1]}, :count=>10}
```

Note that we are not interested in transforming the key itself, just having it on hand while transforming the corresponding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Hash#deep_merge!`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Hash/deep_merge%21) (provided by `ActiveSupport`) like so:

```
keys_not_to_transform = ['id', 'count']

transform_value = lambda do |value|
    s = value.to_s
    if s.present? && /\A[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?\z/.match?(s)
      BigDecimal(s)
    else
      value
    end
end

transform = Proc.new do |key,value|
  if keys_not_to_transform.include? key.to_s
    value
  elsif value.is_a?(Array)
    value.map! do |v| 
      v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.deep_merge!(v,&transform) : transform_value.(v)
    end 
  else   
    transform_value.(value)
  end  
end

response = { result: 'ok', errors: [], data: { id: '123', price: '100.0', quotes: ['1.0', '2.0'], other: [{id: '124', price: '17.0'}] }, count: 10 }

response.deep_merge!(response, &transform)
```

This outputs:

```
#=>{:result=>"ok", :errors=>[], :data=>{:id=>"123", :price=>0.1e3, :quotes=>[0.1e1, 0.2e1], :other=>[{:id=>"124", :price=>0.17e2}]}, :count=>10}
```

Comment: I think you almost got it. This falls short with array values tho, right? For example `{ foo: ['1'] }` or `{ foo: [ { bar: "1"} ] }` doesn't get transformed.

Comment: @randomguy `transform_values` is not going to handle that either nor does your transformation code. You will need to handle `Array` objects as they are not `Hash`es and thus not "mergeable". The answer solves your question and transforming the Array objects should be fairly trivial

Comment: Not true. `deep_transform_values` does handle arrays https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_transform_values.rb#L29-L30. See for example https://gist.github.com/alexhanh/f1b9088855f983c14e315d284e8cf2b8

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work https://gist.github.com/alexhanh/ef91923ada4c8ce53822b41232ece0ff

Comment: @randomguy updated to use a lambda and a Proc to handle the recursion

Answer (score 1):

I'd just implement the necessary transformation logic with plain old Ruby and a bit of recursion, no external dependencies needed. For example:

```rb
def transform(hash, ignore_keys: [])
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      result[key] = transform(value, ignore_keys: ignore_keys)
    elsif ignore_keys.include?(key.to_s)
      result[key] = value
    elsif value.to_s =~ /\A[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?\z/
      result[key] = BigDecimal(value)
    else
      result[key] = value
    end
  end
end

keys_not_to_transform = %w[id count]
response = { result: 'ok', errors: [], data: { id: '123', price: '100.0' }, count: 10 }

transform(response, ignore_keys: keys_not_to_transform)
# => {:result=>"ok", :errors=>[], :data=>{:id=>"123", :price=>#<BigDecimal:5566613bb128,'0.1E3',9(18)>}, :count=>10}
```

Comment: Nice however the dependencies already exist based on this being rails. Also should move the ignore keys to the top if so you don't traverse Hash unnecessarily. Finally this still does not handle Array which was updated into the original question

Comment: @engineersmnky good catch about the redundant hash traversal. And yes, I've missed the fact the initial question has changed a bit...